# OBIEE on android

Tags: android, frameworks, business-intelligence, obiee

I am new to OBIEE and would like to know that are there any frameworks or ways available to develop mobile applications for OBIEE so that i can view dashboard and reports on Android device itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are now two options for OBIEE on mobiles devices, including Android:

1. [Mobile App Designer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e40220/toc.htm) - viewable on any HTML5 web browser
2. [Oracle BI Mobile for Android](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52471_01/bi.1111/e52132/toc.htm) - native app for Android, available on Play store

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the OBIEE mobile application is just for Apple devices.

Comment: This answer is now out of date; there is a native OBIEE application for Android.

Answer (score 0):

OBIEE does not have an Android App but, you can use the [GO URL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e16364/apiwebintegrate.htm#CACCHBHC) to retrieve Analysis and Dashboards and render them in the browser.

Comment: This answer is now out of date; there is a native OBIEE application for Android.

Answer (score 0):

OBIEE has a very detailed SOA framework for integrating with external application it is part of Fusion Middleware.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e16364/soa_overview.htm#BIEIT137

This SOA framework can expose reports that are configured in OBIEE. If you familear with JDeveloper then you can import the service as JAX-RPC/ WS to implement you coding.

Hope this helps...